# RPi3 - Raspbian Pixel WiFi Connect not working

Tags: wifi, pixel

I successfully installed Raspbian on my RPi, and tried to connect wifi on my room, but it's not working.

If I connect non-password wifi (maybe my neighborhood's), It's working well.

But, mine has simple password (abcd1234).

I clicked my wifi and input the password, and click 'OK' button, 
no changes. none of message dialog.

I changed my wifi setup [WPAPSK/WPA2PSK] to [WPA2PSK], and tried again,

but couldn't solve the problem.

Is there other way to connect to my WiFi?

Comment: What channel is your WiFi using? I don't know supported channels for Korea (if you are in Korea), but a lot of people have had problems with the on-board WiFi of the Pi3B, because it is much more particular about the supported modes. `sudo iwlist wlan0 channel` will show what channels are supported.

Comment: @Milliways My WiFi channel was 11 (before I fix the problem). and I changed using country, The channel is now 9.

Comment: and `sudo iwlist wlan0 channel` during wifi connection, It said 1~11 channel available. and without connection, It said 1~13 channel available.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem,

I don't know why, but it is related with WiFi configuration.

I access to 192.168.0.1 for wifi setup (On my Windows Desktop), 
and change "using country(사용국가, 使用國家)" Korea to US, and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in "Dutch" mode. I have reset the localisation to GB, but it didn't help for me. Then, I have re-installed the complete system, making sure the language is "GB" from the NOOBS-installation-screen. After this, I could enable wlan0 from the icon without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

There have been updates to pixel so try this:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: These commands won't update pixel, they will update the OS to a newer version.